# CSRFTOKEN not defined on incognito

Tags: reactjs, django, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-token

I am working on an application that has the backend on django and the frontend on react. The problem I am facing now is `csrftoken`. All my forms are submitted on using a normal browser but if I use `Incognito` mode I cannot submit the request because the `csrftoken is not found`.

The function I use to receive the `csrftoken`:

```
const getCsrfToken = () => {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; csrftoken=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
};
```

I know I can use `@csrf_exempt` on views but I want to keep my app secure. Is there any way to generate that csrftoken even if users use incognito mode?

Comment: Compare the value of `document.cookie` in a normal and an incognito window. You can do this with a debugger or a `console.log` statement. Edit your question to include the result of this comparison (unless it is already clear by then).